# Images from Google Cloud Storage no longer display after GAE 1.8.8 update

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-storage

After updating to GAE 1.8.8 and the GCS Client to r127 my code that displays images no longer works using the Development Server or Production.  Code that worked previously now throughs the following error in development:

```
Blob with key 'encoded_gs_file:blahblahblah' does not exist
```

Note blahblahblah is just my shorthand for a long string.

Below is how I generate my url.  This has always worked in the past.

```
bkey = blobstore.create_gs_key('/gs/mybucket/myfile.jpg')
url = images.get_serving_url(bkey, size=170, crop=True, secure_url=True)
```

Below is a stack trace from the development server:

```
ERROR    2013-11-21 20:35:31,767 images_stub.py:405] Blob with key 'encoded_gs_file:c2l0ZS1hdWRpdC1waW5uYWNsZWNyZS9CYXR0ZXJ5L3Bob3Rvcy8yMDEzMTEyMTAwMTEyOUBhNzllYmQwNC05YWY3LTRhMWItYTg3My1mZGIwYjI5MjNjNzguanBn' does not exist
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/images/images_stub.py", line 401, in _OpenBlob
blobstore_stub.BlobstoreServiceStub.ToDatastoreBlobKey(blob_key))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 651, in Get
return GetAsync(keys, **kwargs).get_result()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 612, in get_result
return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1541, in __get_hook
entities = extra_hook(entities)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 620, in local_extra_hook
raise datastore_errors.EntityNotFoundError()
EntityNotFoundError
ApplicationError(1,)
```

Reading the release notes for GAE 1.8.8 I cannot see anything else I need to change in my code.  Any pointers as to what I am doing wrong would be great.

Comment: I don't have a solution for you, but I'm surprised your code worked pre-1.8.8. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922833/404-error-when-saving-to-gcs-with-client-library-on-localhost-running-dev-appser

Comment: I saw that and it pointed me to updating my GCS client to r127.  After updating to r127 I could save files again.  Now that I can save files just fine I think my problem is a bit different then that post.  It appears that the images.get_serving_url is returning an improper url.

Comment: I modified the sample from the GCS Client r127 to upload a photo then attempt to get a usable URL.  I find that the blob key used when writing the file is not what I get back when using blobstore.create_gs_key.  Could there be a problem with create_gs_key in blobstore due to the changes in the new GCS library?  I'm running out of ideas other then revert back to GAE 1.8.7 and an old GCS client library.